# How to clear memory route once component is destroyed, react-router url not working

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React-router and it works fine while I'm clicking on link buttons, but when I refresh my webpage it does not load what I want.

For instance, I am in localhost/joblist and everything is fine because I arrived here pressing a link. But If I refresh the webpage I get:

Cannot GET /joblist
By default, it didn't work like this. Initially I had my URL as localhost/#/ and localhost/#/joblist and they worked perfectly fine. But I don't like this kind of URL, so trying to erase that #, I wrote:

```
Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler) {
 React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

This problem does not happen with localhost/, this one always returns what I want.

Comment: Are you using any library for routing like react-router? Also show the code for the routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing context here, but anyways let me know if this is helpful

Your Webpack server to expect the routes.

```
    devServer: {
       historyApiFallback: true,
       contentBase: './',
       hot: true
    },
```